# Formula csv powershell? is it possible?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a formula that I would like to put in the "Unique Account Name" column. I know that a CSV file is data only, I was wondering what the best way is to add a formula to the Unique Account name tab and to auto populate the rest of the column (if possible). Not sure if this is even possible or not and I wanted some clarification.

[image]

I am trying to implement this under the unique account Name. IF(G2="Domain",E2&" - "&C2,A2 & " - "&C2)

My code:

```
 Import-Csv 'U:\Local Group Members.csv' | where-Object {($_.Name0 -eq "administrators") -and ($_.caption0 -match "Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 7 Professional|Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8 Pro|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Enterprise|Microsoft Windows 8.1 Pro")} |
Select-Object "Netbios_name0", "Name0", "Account0","category0","Domain0","Unique Account Name","caption0", "Excluded" |
Export-Csv -notypeinformation U:\LGMbestone.csv
```

My question is, is it possible to add the formula to this file? Or would I have to export it as a different file type and make a new script?

I am new to PowerShell.

[image: End result I would like for that column to be like]

Comment: It is a little unclear from your question what data you're trying to get into the UniqueAccountName property and how the data in the Local Group Members.csv file is matched to the data in the LGMbestone.csv file. Could you elaborate on that at all and provide some sample data?

Comment: @MarkWragg I am trying to automate a report, then I have a formula that works in excel if I would put it in there. I added the Unique Account Name from the script. The data in Local Group Members.csv file is being compressed from the script and I am renaming it to LGMbestone.csv

Comment: Can you share the Excel formula? That might help me understand what you're doing.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what you expect UniqueAccountName to have as a value when the script has run. FYI you can edit your question to add more information.

Comment: @MarkWragg here is the formula I want to implement.   IF(G2="Domain",E2&" - "&C2,A2 & "  - "&C2)

Comment: Assumedly you've replicated the table that references in the Local Group Members CSV? If so what are the column headers?

Comment: @MarkWragg they are the same as the replicated

Comment: Why does your Excel formula look for column G to contain "Domain" but your PowerShell code looks for it to contain an OS name?

Comment: I have amended my answer, does that help?

Comment: @MarkWragg I had a little error on there, now the formula will work.

Comment: @MarkWragg how would I implement your code with mine then?

Comment: @MarkWragg as in adding what I previously had and what you gave me to work properly together.

Comment: Does my code not work to replace yours? Although I'm still not clear why you have a list of operating systems.

Comment: @MarkWragg if you look back up at my picture, I switched it to how it is supposed to be. So the formula will make a lot more sense now. In the code I had, I was adding the unique account name to column F.

Comment: @MarkWragg what I am doing in my code is keeping all the administrators in the Name0 and all of the operating systems. Which I need to keep that code to be able to run yours. Otherwise I would not have everything filtered the way I want it to be.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming your CSV file already has a blank 'Unique Account Name' column and replicating the Excel formula that you shared in the comments, something like this might be what you're looking for:

```
Import-CSV U:\Local Group Members.csv | ForEach-Object {

    If ($_.Caption0 -eq 'Domain') { 
        $_.UniqueAccountName = "$($_.Domain0) - $($_.Account0)" 
    } Else { 
        $_.UniqueAccountName = "$($_.Nebios_name0) - $($_.Account0)" 
    }

    Write-Output $_

} | Export-Csv -notypeinformation U:\LGMbestone.csv
```

If your input CSV file doesn't already have that column to start with, you could do something like this (to create it in the object):

```
Import-CSV U:\Local Group Members.csv | ForEach-Object {

    If ($_.Caption0 -eq 'Domain') { 
        $UniqueAccountName = "$($_.Domain0) - $($_.Account0)" 
    } Else { 
        $UniqueAccountName = "$($_.Nebios_name0) - $($_.Account0)" 
    }

    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'UniqueAccountName' -Value $UniqueAccountName -PassThru

} | Export-Csv -notypeinformation U:\LGMbestone.csv
```

It's hard to say if these exactly match your requirements without having some sample data from both CSV files and a clearer explanation of what you expect the end result to look like.